# Is it possible to solve analytically this integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

For my research, I've been modelling some experimental results and I stumbled upon this integral: 
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+e^{ax-b}}dx$$
where $x_0$, $x_1$, $a$ and $b$ $\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I've been trying to solve it analytically for a while but it seems there no solution in terms of ordinary functions.
Is there any way to solve the following integral analytically?

Comment: Even $\frac{1}{x(1+e^x)}$ doesn't seem to have an analytical solution. You can check the Wikipedia page for the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Indefinite_integrals) which is somewhat related to your integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $0 < x_0 < x_1$, $a>0$ and $e^{ax_0-b} \gg1$, we could probably write
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{a x-b}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} e^{-(ax-b)n}$$ making
$$I=\int\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+e^{ax-b}}dx=\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{e^{-(ax-b)n}}x\,dx$$ that is to say
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} e^{bn}\,\text{Ei}(-a n x)$$

Trying, just as an example, with $a=1$, $b=2$, $x_0=2$ and varying $x_1$,we should obtain
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x_1 & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 3 & 0.1572187183 & 0.1572187192 \\
 4 & 0.2118594679 & 0.2118594691 \\
 5 & 0.2296373488 & 0.2296373497 \\
 6 & 0.2352676157 & 0.2352676169 \\
 7 & 0.2370523888 & 0.2370523897 \\
 8 & 0.2376247135 & 0.2376247144 \\
 9 & 0.2378107346 & 0.2378107355 \\
 10 & 0.2378719542 & 0.2378719553
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, $b>0$ makes the convergence not fast. With $b \leq 0$, it is just a dream.

Answer (score 1):

At least [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) version 5.43.0 on Fedora 31 doesn't know how to integrate this. In general, computer algebra systems include algorithms that are able to integrate anything that has an antiderivative. Perhaps for specific values of $a, b, x_0, x_1$ you can get a formula, or you'll have to resort to numerical integration (try e.g. [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) or [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for such manipulations).